# Is it possible to install App store build from xcode to test phone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, app-store

I am not sure of it. It seems for one of my app I can install the app store target to my phone. But cannot debug.

But for the second app, it gives invalid entitlements or no provisioning profile exists etc.

For ad hoc build, I can install, then the app exit (no debugging). Later in the iPhone I can run it.

Comment: Ad hoc target is installed on the device from xcode. It is possible to send push message to the app. But not possible to debug directly from xcode. I had to use NSLog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as my knowledge concern it is not possible.

Comment: Badij is wright, you can't run Ad-Hoc or Appstore build via XCode. the debugger will not hook to the app if the entitlements don't allow debugging. AppStore build can't even be install to my knowledge.

Comment: For ad hoc build, I can install, then the app exit (no debugging). Later in the iPhone I can run it.

Comment: Thanks Babji. I expect more support for your answer. People, if you agree, plz upvote Babji's answer. I was confused, since one other app really installed using app store target on the iPhone.